# Export out CSV Files from SQL Based of Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to generate multiple csv exports from a table in SQL based off the date field in this table.  The date is different for many records.  I would like to export records containing the same date to a csv.  Every time a different date is found, a csv will be exported containing the data for the selected columns and date.  How can I go about creating a script to perform this type of action.  Is there a way to have the script go through the date column automatically and export out the data with the 4 fields selected and generated a csv for those docs that share the same date, etc.

**Example:**

```
Select Box, Highprice, Lowprice, Date
where date="2016-01-31"
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just SQL server on its own.  You should use something like Visual Studio (BIDS), to write a package where you define all the criteria and write the file.

Comment: you can develop an SSIS package to do exactly that

Comment: Why would you want to create CSVs out of something you have in SQL Server?  Just trying to get a feeling for the overall objective. The export to CSV may be an unnecessary work around in and of itself.

Comment: The CSV is a report for the records to be viewed outside of SQL for those who do have SQL.

Comment: Kamran: are there instructions on how to create the SSIS package?  Can you guide me?

Comment: Have you considered making a refresh-able Excel file?  That is, just tie a data pull directly to your SQL server, and refresh it whenever you need to.  the only drawback there is that whoever refreshes it would need the ODBC connection.  But that's not even necessary if the file is for others and read-only.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggest this is not a good method. Also there are few issues related to this.

- By default, sql server is not granting permission to execute xp_cmdshell
- The files will be generated in the Server and should have proper accessing privileges for that.
- I gave you the way to do it for a static date and you may need to write a cursor to loop all days that are needed.

  select @sql = 'bcp YourDB.dbo.YourTbl where date=''2016-01-31'' out
  c:\temp\CSV2016-01-31.csv -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servername
  exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql